# Average order in different power of Mobius function and prime number theorem

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory

The Prime number theorem is equivalent to the argument$$\sum_{n\ge 1}\dfrac{\mu(n)}{n}=0$$
Is it possible to imply that $\displaystyle \sum_{n\ge 1}\dfrac{\mu(n)}{n}=\prod_{p \text { prime }}\left(1-\dfrac{1}{p}\right)$?
If it is the case, then by Merten's theorem $$\prod_{p\text{ prime }}\left(1-\dfrac{1}{p}\right)=\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\prod_{p\le x}\left(1-\dfrac{1}{p}\right)=\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\dfrac{e^{-\gamma}}{\log x}=0$$

and therefore, the PNT. This recall me that it might not be the case. Another analogous one is that can we write $\displaystyle \sum_{n\ge 1}\dfrac{\mu(n)}{\sqrt n}=\prod_{p}\left(1-\dfrac{1}{\sqrt p}\right)$? And, as far as I concern $\displaystyle \sum_{n\ge 1}\dfrac{\mu(n)}{n^\alpha}$ converges if $\alpha >1$, even when $\alpha =1$ as it is equivalent to PNT. I wonder if $\displaystyle \sum_{n\ge 1}\dfrac{\mu(n)}{\sqrt n}$ converges as well, or is there any hint to tackle with? I would really appreciate for any help, thank you.

Comment: You indeed have $$\sum_{n \geqslant 1} \frac{\mu(n)}{n} = \prod_{p \text{ prime}} \biggl(1 - \frac{1}{p}\biggr)\,.$$ However, the difficult part is showing that the sum converges, i.e. that $$\lim_{x \to \infty} \sum_{1 \leqslant n \leqslant x} \frac{\mu(n)}{n}$$ exists.

Comment: In the book I've just read shows that $$\sum_{n\le x}\dfrac{\mu(n)}{n}\le 1$$, so this conclude the theorem?

Comment: No, since we have positive as well as negative terms, boundedness is not sufficient to deduce convergence.

Comment: If, actually, the summation is $\ge -1$ would not be enough? since it may be fluctuated like the limit of $\sin$?

Comment: It's not enough. One must show that the partial sums don't oscillate (or, that the amplitude of the oscillations tends to $0$), and that's not so easy.

Comment: As for the general case, we *know* that $$\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{\mu(n)}{n^s}$$ converges for $\operatorname{Re} s \geqslant 1$, and that it diverges for $\operatorname{Re} s \leqslant \frac{1}{2}$. We don't know whether the series converges or diverges in between, but we sort-of expect that it converges for $\operatorname{Re} s > \frac{1}{2}$ (that's equivalent to the Riemann hypothesis). We also know that when the series converges, then its value is $1/\zeta(s)$. And the only zero of $1/\zeta(s)$ is at $s = 1$. Since the product $$\prod_p \biggl(1 - \frac{1}{p^{\alpha}}\biggr)$$ ...

Comment: ... diverges to $0$ for $0 < \alpha \leqslant 1$ it follows that *if* the series converges for some $\alpha < 1$, then the value of the series at $s = \alpha$ is different from the value of the product.

Comment: $\displaystyle \sum_{n\ge 1}\dfrac{\mu(n)}{\sqrt n}$ diverges because otherwise we'll have for any $t$ fixed, in particular for some $t$ such that $\zeta(1/2+it)=0$: $\zeta(1/2+a+it) = o( \Re(a)^{-1})$ as $a \to 0$. See the end of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_series#Abscissa_of_convergence